# wcf rest ierrorhandler webfaultexception

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, ierrorhandler

I have a WCF 4 Rest service that is to be consumed by a java client and also an c# mvc3 client. The response content needs to be returned as json.

I want to be able to return any exception/faults back to clients in a consistent way.  I read that WebFaultException should be used and indeed it works fine.

However, I do not want to pollute my application logic project with WebFaultExceptions as it may be used by a non web project.

I therefore looked at implementing IErrorHandler in the WCF Rest service to catch ANY exceptions and then for specific ones i.e. ValidationException, return the exception as a fault wrapped in a WebFaultException. However this doesn't seem to work and I get the following Http 504 response when called form fiddler

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

I've reduced the code to its bare bones to show the essence of what I'm doing.

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, 
                         MessageVersion version, 
                         ref Message fault)
{
    var ex = new WebFaultException<Exception>(
                                      new Exception("you can't do that"), 
                                      HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

    var xmf = ex.CreateMessageFault();
    fault = Message.CreateMessage(version,
                                  null,
                                  xmf,
                                 new DataContractJsonSerializer(xmf.GetType()));
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to use WebFaultException from IErrorHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code from [Carlos's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx). It helps me in the past.

```
public class ValidationAwareErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    IErrorHandler originalErrorHandler;
    public ValidationAwareErrorHandler(IErrorHandler originalErrorHandler)
    {
        this.originalErrorHandler = originalErrorHandler;
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        return error is ValidationException || this.originalErrorHandler.HandleError(error);
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        ValidationException validationException = error as ValidationException;
        if (validationException != null)
        {
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, null, new ValidationErrorBodyWriter(validationException));
            HttpResponseMessageProperty prop = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
            prop.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            prop.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, prop);
            fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));
        }
        else
        {
            this.originalErrorHandler.ProvideFault(error, version, ref fault);
        }
    }

    class ValidationErrorBodyWriter : BodyWriter
    {
        private ValidationException validationException;
        Encoding utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

        public ValidationErrorBodyWriter(ValidationException validationException)
            : base(true)
        {
            this.validationException = validationException;
        }

        protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("root");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "object");

            writer.WriteStartElement("ErrorMessage");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "string");
            writer.WriteString(this.validationException.ValidationResult.ErrorMessage);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("MemberNames");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "array");
            foreach (var member in this.validationException.ValidationResult.MemberNames)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("item");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "string");
                writer.WriteString(member);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen Carlos's solution before, it just seems a bit strange that if we implement IErrorHandler we essentially have to hand craft the message, whereas using WebFaultException from the service direct doeseverything for us i.e. json/xml formatting.  Also the mvc app used to be able to catch the FaultExceptions (it was previously a Soap service) but I'm not sure how I catch them now?

Comment: WebFaultException derive from FaultException and implement a new interface IFaultExecption. WCF 4.0 was modified in this way (missing in 3.5). IErrorHandler enables you to explicitly control the SOAP fault generated. Using it for RestService is not the correct way. For Better Rest Support, use the new Aspnet WebApi.

Comment: Moving to WebApi at this stage of the project is a not an option I'm afraid. So if I use Carlos's solution is there an easy/accepted way of catching the exception in the mvc app?

Comment: it depends how you call your service... with a restful service you can simply create an HttpWebRequest. If an error occurs, RESTful practices expect that we set an HTTP status code  in the response to generally classify why the request failed.Because the status code is probably not enough, an obvious detail item should be added in the response text.

Comment: but remember that webfaultexception could also be used with non-REST endpoints and behaves like a regular FaultException. When using a WCF REST endpoint, the response format of the serialized fault is determined in the same way as a non-fault response. For more information about WCF REST formatting

Comment: Essentially I used your suggested solution with a variant of http://kenneththorman.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/wcf-rest-exception-handling.html on the mvc client side.  I agree though that its probably best to go with the WebApi in future. Thanks